# Document editor and viewer tool for viewing, editing and saving a document in the same location in webapp

Tags: google-docs-api

In our web application product we want to view & edit the word,excel and pdf file and save to web application server location. List of file will be list in grid the same file has to edited and saved

please help us with any solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look on zoho remote api editor...Though they are not covering all your requirements,they are the only one giving this unique solution in the online document editor technology...

Please find the below link

https://apihelp.wiki.zoho.com/Remote-API-Overview.html

Comment: Any other suggestions for this problem